# Fetching queries from MySQL and printing it in a javascript calendar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, calendar

I have a hardcoded javascript calendar and I need to print the events from my database which is a PHP MySQL server side database. But I'm not sure how to fetch the queries from mysql and print it into the javascript calendar :/ I found something that makes use of VBSCRIPT but its very confusing :/

Comment: What JS calendar are you using? VBScript is not relevant on a server that uses PHP. There are so many details left out that it's almost impossible to help.

Comment: It is a hardcoded calendar which I found from a JavaScript calendar book. The codes are too long to be posted here tho :/

Comment: So you just need to know how to get data from a database? Use http://pastebin.com/ if the code is really too long, and then post a link to it in your question.

Comment: This is the link. http://pastebin.com/gHwaAicT Basically I need to know how to print the fetched queries from mysql into this calendar. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Look for support forums for the calendar code, or a beginner help forum. codingforums.com might be a good place to start. I don't think stackoverflow is what you need for this kind of problem, which needs a lot of support, not an "answer".

Answer (score 0):

The general outline:

Use PHP to access the database and fetch rows of calendar data (using a query). Then, print it out to a Javascript data structure like JSON or native Javascript that is loaded into the browser. Then, work with the Javascript calendar code to load the data into the view the browser presents to the user on the webpage.

There's a lot of variation that can occur here, but roughly (in semi-psuedo code):

**Within page contains the calendar (outputs in JSON notation)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Events', $link);

$count = 0;

echo "var events = {";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($count !== 0) echo ",";
    echo "{";
    echo "'eventid':'" . add_slashes($row['eventid']) . "',";
    echo "'title':'" . add_slashes($row['title']) . "',";
    echo "'description':'" . add_slashes($row['description']) . "',";
    echo "'date':'" . add_slashes($row['date']) . "',";
    echo "'time':'" . add_slashes($row['time']) . "'";
    echo "}";
    count++;
}

echo "};";    

?>

$calendar = new Calendar(events);

</script>
```

Of course, there are a number of ways that this could be done, but this is one way it could flow. This is only an example; dropping this code into a PHP page on a server will not work, it's only meant to demonstrate how in general it could flow.